# Sweave + sciposter conflict prevents italics in title

Tags: sweave, sciposter

After some fooling around, I have determined that when package Sweave is loaded, italics in the title of a sciposter document is ignored (though underline works).  I don't know enough to read the style files and find the problem.  Here's a simple example.  Comment the Sweave in or out to see the effect.  TIA for any advice!

```
\documentclass[landscape]{sciposter}

\usepackage{Sweave}

\title{My Title Has \emph{Italics} But They Don't Work if Sweave is Loaded}
\author{Johnny Be Good}
\institute{Good Times Institute}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Some text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Sweave` package loads the `ae` package, which changes all the fonts to the "Almost European Computer Modern" font, which apparently doesn't have boldface italics.  You can see this, because your sample document produces the following warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/aess/bx/it' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/aess/bx/n' instead on input line 10.
```

You can solve the problem by adding:

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

to your preamble after loading the `Sweave` package.

This will undo the `ae` font changes, but otherwise should look the same.